# Как в JavaScript добавить тег комментарий в код HTML?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста.
В JavaScript создается ссылка и вставляется в HTML.
Как обернуть ссылку в "noindex"? / Как добавить Тег "комментарий"?

В итоговом коде должно получиться:

```
 <!--noindex--> <a href="/">ссылка</a> <!--/noindex-->
```

Comment: Можно создать по комментарию по бокам ссылки при помощи [Document.createComment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createComment).

Comment: большое спасибо

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<a id="link" href="#"></a>
```

JS

```
const $link = document.getElementById('link')

$link.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `<!--noindex-->`)
$link.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<!--noindex-->`)
```

Так можно добавить то что ты хотел

```
 <!--noindex--> <a href="/">ссылка</a> <!--/noindex-->
```

но сама ссылка при этом закомментирована не будет, т.к.  `<!--/noindex-->` это просто закомментированная строка.